# error Fatal exception main

Tags: android

I have created a menu page for my project with image buttons, last night when I tired it on my samsung phone everything appeared to be working fine no errors all links worked, however today I am trying to run the same application on my emulator I am getting these errors I have made no changes in the code, can some one help me where I am going wrong I have both the codes below XML and JAVA

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


public class Menu extends Activity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    ImageButton Bmi = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibBmi);
       Bmi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Bmi.class);                
             startActivityForResult(ourIntent, 0);

                }

    });

       ImageButton Camera = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibCamera);
       Camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
       Intent ourIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Camera.class);
             startActivityForResult(ourIntent, 0);

                }

    });

       ImageButton Resizeme = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibResizeme);
       Resizeme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Resizeme.class);
             startActivityForResult(ourIntent, 0);

                }

    });
       ImageButton Maps = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibMaps);
       Maps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Maps.class);
             startActivityForResult(ourIntent, 0);

                }

    });

    }


}


 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/lightbackground">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibCamera"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="97dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Camera"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/camera1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bStayfit"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="97dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ibResizeme"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/stayfit"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/abs_cartoon" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibMaps"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="97dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bBulkup"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Maps"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/maps1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibBmi"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="97dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ibCamera"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/BMI"
        android:src="@drawable/bmi" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibResizeme"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="97dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bStayfit"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ibBmi"
        android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/resizeme"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/looseweight" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ibCamera"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ibCamera"
        android:src="@drawable/cameralogo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ibResizeme"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ibBmi"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ibCamera"
        android:src="@drawable/resizemelogo" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bBulkup"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ibCamera"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/bulkup"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/dumbbell1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ibCamera"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ibCamera"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
        android:src="@drawable/bulkuplogo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bStayfit"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ibResizeme"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:src="@drawable/stayfitlogo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/mapslogo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ibBmi"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ibBmi"
        android:src="@drawable/bmilogo" />

</RelativeLayout>


 The errors I am getting are:
```

as a new user I am unable to upload pictures but the main error I get it Fatal Exception main follows by :

```
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gethench/com.example.gethench.Menu}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #54: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #54: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at com.example.gethench.Menu.onCreate(Menu.java:18)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     ... 11 more
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
12-18 16:20:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1024):     ... 24 more
```

Comment: i think you have issue with `android:id="@+id/ibResizeme"` button can you try it after removing it?

Answer (score 0):

Your layout seems to have multiple relationships between several buttons. Have you tried opening the layout in Eclipse? I guess you somehow created incompatible positions between some of them (but, since you have referenced several drawables, it would be easier for you to find them than for anyone else who's trying to help)

Comment: I am using Eclipse to code my application, unless there is a different way to open the layout in Eclipse, the funny this is last night everything was working fine :S all of a sudden it started to crash :(

Comment: I think (I'm not sure, though) the xml resources aren't necessarily compiled as soon as they are saved, unlike the .java files. So, if you made some change to the xml file, tested it and closed Eclipse, the problem might have shown up the next time you opened it. My advice still stands, though: try to open the xml file in the designer and look if you see any warnings/errors in your xml file.

Comment: I have checked the XML design layout no errors whats so ever the only warning I am getting is "[Accessibility] Missing contentDescription attribute on image" but I dont think its much of an issue as I read in one of the previous Q's asked regarding this so the app still should run :(

Comment: Right. The warning shouldn't cause you any problems at all. Still, from your error I'd look at the layout files. Look in your resource directories as well, there might be a missing drawable and/or one with an invalid name, for instance.